# Run unittests with multiple random values

Tags: unit-testing, pytest, nose, python-unittest

Having variable like `list1=[1,2,3,4,5]` and another  `list2=[2,3,4,5,6]` I want to make assertions about each item in first list like

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
     for num in list1:
         self.assertIn(num, list2)
```

And I need unique name for each test. I've something like this in `nose` or `py.test` package, but can not find where exactly.

Comment: So, what is your question? What have you done so far and where do you need help?

Answer (score 0):

Using parametrization: http://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html

```
import pytest

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('num', list1)
def test_contains(num):
    assert num in list2
```